# Code compliance

Tags: java, jsp, sonarqube, findbugs

Whenever sonar comes across these kind of imports in JSP it flags them noncompliance with the below rule.

Is it not allowed to import the Java classes which we'll be using in scriptslets?
Do we need to explicitly provide the class being imported every time we use it

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Date, java.sql.Timestamp, java.util.HashMap ,import="java.sql.Date"%>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, it's *required* to import the classes you'll be using in your scriptlets. However...

It's *reeeally* not a good idea to be doing heavy Java logic in a JSP. I say this as someone who once had to close a `connection` leak in a JSP. (>_<)

It took me weeks to find it because you don't *expect* a JSP to be talking to the database. You expect database communication - along with the rest of the logic - to be in the `.java` files. So this rule is flagging your Java imports as a way of saying "Hey, move this logic to the servlet and use the JSP for pure presentation!"

Now that I've gotten the sermon out of my system, I'll point out that this rule doesn't flag any packages by default, so whatever it's flagging was configured for flagging by your SonarQube administrator (or designees). So you should probably have the discussion of why you can't use these classes with her.